# Python Dictonary Class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to get my class working but I can only seem to add 2 items and I can't add the duplicate item.

I have also tried using for loops but I can't seem to get that to work either.

List of words to add:

```
words = Bag()
words.add('once')
words.add('twice')
words.add('twice')
```

My code:

```
class Bag:

    def __init__(self):
        """Create a new empty bag."""
        self.bag = dict()


    def add(self, item):
        """Add one copy of item to the bag. Multiple copies are allowed."""

        if not item in self.bag:
            self.bag[item] = 1
        else:
            self.bag[item] += 1

        print(self.bag)
```

Comment: But... your code is working.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Do you get an error? What is your expected vs actual output?

Comment: `for x in self.bag.values():
  print(x)`

Comment: thank you for your replies, my code works to a point i cant get my code to add 'twice' twice into my dictionary only shows 2 entries and not 3 item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want results to look like `{'once': 1, 'twice': 2, 'twice': 3}`.

This is not possible, you can't have same key multiple times in a dict. But you can get structure like `[{'once': 1}, {'twice': 2}, {'twice': 3}]` with this code:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        """Create a new empty bag."""
        self.index = 0
        self.bag = []


    def add(self, item):
        """Add one copy of item to the bag. Multiple copies are allowed."""
        self.index += 1
        self.bag.append({item: self.index})
```

Comment: thank you for your replies, my code works to  a point i cant get my code to add 'twice' twice into my dictionary only shows 2 entries and not 3 items

Comment: How should correct result looks like? Isn't `{'once': 1, 'twice': 2}` correct?

Comment: the correct result should look like this {'once': 1, 'twice': 2, 'twice': 3}

Comment: I edited my answer. You can't get what you want but you can have something similar.

Comment: Genius! thank you! I understand where I went wrong now!